# how to have different users/actors in a particular node in corda4 as it is not available in corda3?

Tags: corda

Example- In a GlobalBank usecase, it is not feasible to have each and every customer in different nodes along with all different banks in world with different nodes, so can all the customers be made an actors/users in node "Customer" and all banks under node "Bank" and hence making only 2 nodes in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Corda 4 will not introduce support for this feature.

Support for many identities will be introduced in a future, as yet undecided, release. You can see the roadmap for this feature, called Project Maximus, here: https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/message/469.

Comment: So, how to proceed with the query? Does making rpcusers will suffice the desired query?